# Property "window" not found on object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This came up in another question (kindly answered by [meronix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585749/meronix)) but I curious to learn a little more about what is going on here, is this a LLVM/Clang issue, or are the two statements different in someway.

[image]

I know I can fix this by adding (See below), so more curious than anything ...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two statements *are* different. A property can only be used if the type of the lvalue declares the property. This is because the getter and setter for the property might be non-obvious (often the case with boolean properties, where the getter is explicitly set to `isSomething`.) The compiler cannot infer that without strong type info.

The `[lvalue message]` syntax, however, has no such ambiguity, so the compiler allows it. Since the type of the lvalue is `id`, any known message can be sent to it without a compiler warning. The compiler will only warn if two signatures correspond to the same selector (for instance, one class has `- (UIWindow *)window` and another has `- (int)window`.)

The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol defines a `window` property, so when you explicitly type your object as `id <UIApplicationDelegate>`, the compiler knows about the property and can use it.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for a perfect answer, much appreciated.